# Ajax call is hanging/page loading forever

Tags: ajax, jsf, selectonemenu

i am trying to sync the weekday and a date with each other using ajax in JSF.

It is working fine, except for when I choose the same weekday or date that was entered before or I am leaving the dropdown box without selecting anything.

Endresult is a hanging browser (seemingly loading forever), and I can only 'continue' by reloading.

Here are some code snippets:

xhtml:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="weekdaySelectMenu" showEmptyEntry="false"
        styleClass="dropdown_autoWidth" value="#{record.weekdayId}"
>
        <f:selectItems
            value="#{editCourseValueObjectHolder.weekdayValues.entrySet()}"
            var="entry" itemValue="#{entry.key}" itemLabel="#{entry.value}"/> 
        <f:converter converterId="java.lang.Long" />
        <f:ajax 
             listener="#{record.adjustFirstAppointmentDateToMatchWeekDay}"
            event="valueChange"
         render="#{overlayIds}" 
         execute="@this"    
        />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

bean:

```
...
public void adjustFirstAppointmentDateToMatchWeekDay(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    Long newWeekday = getWeekdayId();
    Calendar firstAppointment = createCalendarOfFirstAppointment();                
    int dayShifter = initDayShifter(newWeekday, firstAppointment);
    shiftDays(newWeekday, firstAppointment, dayShifter);   //Date is set according to weekday    
}
...
```

Any ideas? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Any clues in browser's console? (press F12) E.g. a simple JS error, etc.

Comment: in the browser console, nothing can be seen. as a matter of fact, in case of error the listener method is never even reached. it immediately hangs, no post is even issued.

Comment: So, a client side problem. Hard to answer without a MCVE and clues in console. Shoot in dark: a broken `jsf.ajax.addOnEvent` listener. At least, the non-existent `showEmptyEntry` attribute suggests that there's more at matter in the environment. E.g. some customization, which may or may not be broken. Again, MCVE that.

Comment: thanks balus, you are right, there is (more than some) customization which may be broken. I'll probably have to dig deeper myself before I come back with more information.